# Label children on mouseover d3.js Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I would like to label children of a node upon mouseover. In order to do so, I first created a text attribute for all nodes upon entry. Then I defined a fade function for the mouseover event. 
I'm having difficulty selecting the text attribute of node o in the line o.select("text"). I get an error o.select is not a function. How do I go about doing this?

```
function fade(opacity) {
 return function(d) {
    if (d.group == 5){
     sourceNeighbors[d.index].sort(compare);
     link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {

       if (o.source === d || o.target === d) {
        return opacity;
       }
       else if (isConnected(o.source,d) && isConnected(o.target, d)) {
        return 1;
       }
    return opacity;
    });

        node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {

        if ((d.name != o.name) && isConnected(d, o)) {
            if (opacity == 1) {
                o.select(text)
                    .text("");
            }
            else {
                var num = findIndex(d.index, o.index);
                o.select(text)
                    .text(num.toString());      
            }
        }


            thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
            this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
            return thisOpacity;
        });


    }
 };
}
```

Update : I changed the line to d3.select(o).text("");
 Also here's the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iXnTAhfGNgVY8OPHBBRm) and the d3.js code is in script.js. 
 Also here's what I see on mouseover, [image: graph], the red nodes are missing text.

Comment: What is the definition of `o`?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm new to d3.js but I assume from this line "node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {" that o refers to a node

Comment: Right, so you're not defining this somewhere else? It's hard to figure out what's going on with only partial code and a vague description (I *think* by "created a text attribute" you mean "created a text element"). My guess is that you need `d3.select(this).select("text")` instead of `o.select(text)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, followed your suggestion, I got rid of the error but I still don't know why I can't see the text on the nodes. I did put up the code and a screenshot of what I see on mouseover. Thanks!

Comment: You can't append `text` elements to `circle`s. See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, cool catch! I updated the definitions of node and created a variable gnodes on the plunkr link. I know that I can loop through all nodes and change opacity but how do I loop through all gnodes, check for eligible nodes and then change gnodes text? Is there an example I could emulate? Thanks!